# How do I stop a rolling chair from rolling on a warped floor?

Tags: flooring, floor

My floors are heavily warped. My desk and office chairs are in one of these warped areas. Since my office chair is on wheels that means it rolls down away from where I want it.

How do I eliminate the roll from the chair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three general approaches that will fix the problem:

1. **Make the floor level.**  It isn't clear what you mean by "warped", but if the floor doesn't have any structural problems and you're talking about localized dents rather than general sloping, you could add a rigid laminate layer on top (like Pergo).  If the floor is dented, a plastic chair mat will quickly conform, so the chair will just roll on another layer.
2. **Lock the wheels.**  Replace two of the wheels with locking wheels (not very practical in use), or use wheel chocks as ArchonOSX suggests (might become an inconvenience).
3. **Greatly increase the friction of what the chair rolls on.**  Use a dense rug, as isherwood describes, or a very soft mat.  But this approach will also make it harder to move the chair when you're on it (and if you put a plastic chair mat on top to make it easier to roll, you're back where you started).

Answer (score 1):

I found some chair wheels that replaced the ones on the chair.  When I sit the chair won't roll.  When I get up the chair goes back to rolling.  It works on compression.  They work good. They are called Stel'Air compression sit brake casters 3F-AB2

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.